# default rows per page is overriding items-per-page attribute in v-data-iterator in Vuetify 1.5.2

Tags: pagination, iterator, vuetify.js

I'm working on a vue.js application which uses Vuetify 1.5.2. I'm having trouble setting the items-per-page attribute of the v-data-iterator:

```
            <v-data-iterator
              :items="facilities"
              :items-per-page.sync="facilitiesPerPage"
              content-tag="v-layout"
              rows-per-page-text="Facilities per page"
              row
              wrap
            >
                <v-flex slot="item" slot-scope="props" xs12 sm6 md4 lg3 x12>
                    <facility :facility="props.item"></facility>
                </v-flex>
            </v-data-iterator>
```

```
            data: () => ({
                facilitiesPerPage: 4,
                facilities: [],
                ...
            })
```

According to this, I would think the data-iterator would display 4 items per page. But that's not what's happening. It seems to be defaulting to the number of items per page set in the footer by default. Since we don't set the rows-per-page-items explicitely, it default to [5, 10, 25, 'All'], and 5 is selected by default:

[image]

This seems to be overriding the items-per-page value.

What we want to do is make the items-per-page value dynamic, changing based on the screen width. We lay our items out horizontally, wrapping to multiple rows if necessary, so we want as many items per row as can fit within the screen width. Then facilitiesPerPage is to be calculated based on this number multiplied by the number of rows.

We want something like this:

https://www.codeply.com/p/bFrSEsnq4L

But this only works in Vuetify 2.0, and we have to deal with Vuetify 1.5.2. So we're trying to customize our own design.

What's blocking us now is that the default number of items per page seems to be overriding what we set for items-per-page. Is there any way to prevent this in Vuetify 1.5.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the items-per page dynamically in Vuetify 1.5.2 version.

> Here is the working codepen:
>   https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/oNjqNoG?editors=1010

You have to use the following props to achieve this:

In the version 1.5.2 it is not items-per-page instead it should be **:rows-per-page-items**

To set the rows per page text, you can use this props **:rows-per-page-text="'Facilities per page'"**

Dynamically select the value for rows-per-page, you can use this props **:pagination.sync="paginationSync"** and set the value in object as **{rowsPerPage: 30} // 10, 20, or any**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
      :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPage"
      :rows-per-page-text="'Facilities per page'"
      :pagination.sync="paginationSync"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      paginationSync: {rowsPerPage: 30},
      rowsPerPage: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%'
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```